# In R how to control the cycling direction of values when copying in an array?

Tags: r

I would like to copy some values across rows but the default seems to be cycling over columns, is there an elegant way to achieve what I want ?

The following code I have is:

```
> w = array(NA,dim=c(4,2))
> w
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]   NA   NA
[2,]   NA   NA
[3,]   NA   NA
[4,]   NA   NA
> w[2:4,] = c(2,3)
> w
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]   NA   NA
[2,]    2    3
[3,]    3    2
[4,]    2    3
```

But I would like the values to be cycled over rows to obtain:

```
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]   NA   NA
[2,]    2    3
[3,]    2    3
[4,]    2    3
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create the matrix row-wise, then assign it:

`w[2:4, ] <- matrix(c(2,3), nrow=3, ncol=2, byrow=TRUE)`

Answer (score 7):

You can write a new transposed assignment function:

```
`t<-` <- function(x, value)
{
    t(matrix(value, nrow=ncol(x), ncol=nrow(x)))
}
```

Result:

```
> w = array(NA,dim=c(4,2))
> t(w[2:4,]) = c(2,3)
> w
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]   NA   NA
[2,]    2    3
[3,]    2    3
[4,]    2    3
```

Answer (score 1):

Another **elegant** way :-)

```
 w[2:4,] <- rep(c(2,3),each=length(2:4))
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]   NA   NA
[2,]    2    3
[3,]    2    3
[4,]    2    3
```

Answer (score 1):

```
w[2:4, ] <- matrix(c(2,3),nrow=1)[ rep(1,3), ]
```